# Homology of sublevel sets of a function

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

My question concerned the definition of homology for sublevel sets of a real function. Let consider a real function $f:[0,1]^{d}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and its sublevel sets,
$$F_{t}=\left\{x\in[0,1]^{d}\text{ such that } f(x)\leq t\right\}$$
Without further assumptions on $f$ does it make sense to speak about the homology group of $F_{t}$ (for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$) ? And if the answer is yes, how it is properly defined ? For which homology theory ?

If $f$ is smooth, $F_{t}$ is triangulable (if i am right) and then defining the homology of $F_{t}$ as the simplicial homology of its triangulation make sense. But what if $f$ is less regular ? Typically, is not differentiable or exhibits discontinuities.

Comment: $F_t$ is a topological space, so singular homology makes sense.

Comment: It's certainly not true that $F_t$ is autoamtically triangulable if $f$ is smooth. Any closed subset of the domain can be realized as $F_0$ for some (non-negative) $f$.

Comment: Yes, thank you ! I have just figured this out, doing some quick research (I should certainly have done that before posting my question)

Comment: But anyway, singular homology seems to be the way to go here, thank you !